# EF Core: IEnumerable reference to only part of composite key

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Okay so this might be a question that smells a bit of bad design but now I'm curious to know if it is possible at all :D

I'm doing code first but in a manner where I'm trying to fit the output so I can sort of 1:1 map it from another source and populate the tables.

Consider the following:

```
public class A {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public IEnumerable<B> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class B {
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Key]
   public C Bar { get; set; }

   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class C {
...
}
```

I would like to end up with a database structure that looks like the following:

```
+-------+          +---------------+        +-----+
|   A   |          |       B       |        |  C  |
+-------+          +---------------+        +-----+
|Id   PK+--------->+Id           PK+------->+...  |
|B_Id   |          |C_Id         PK|        +-----+
+-------+          |Description    |
                   +---------------+
```

The tricky/nasty part is to have *A.B_Id* to only reference part of the primary key in B and just have everything that matches in an enumerable.
Everything I've tried seems to result in a new column in B that references back to A but I would like to keep the navigation in the other direction if possible.

Comment: `public IEnumerable<B> Foo { get; set; }` in `A` does not imply `A.B_Id` FK, but `B.A_Id`, so not sure what you are trying to achieve. And no, you can't create FK relationship referencing part of the primary/unique. This comes from relational databases, not EF Core.

Comment: Instead of using a composite Key on B, what if you added a completely separate PK? Key would be NewId, and then Id and Bar can work however you'd like as FKs. If that doesn't work, providing the real-life objects may help for consideration of a different data model.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a Principal key did the job: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

By adding a field to `A` that contains the desired ID of `B`

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<A>(b =>
    {
        b.HasMany(x => x.Foo)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id)
            .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.BId)
    });
```